# Edge attribute color does not go through: R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am having trouble with my edge attribute, where the wrong color is displayed even though it seems like the correct edge attribute is registered. My code is below:

```
  x <- BrM_afterdiagnosis_centrality_urb[BrM_afterdiagnosis_centrality_urb$visitlink == i,]
  g <- graph.data.frame(x[,c(1,2)], directed = FALSE) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("urban", index = x$ahaid, value = x$urban) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("color", index = x$ahaid, value = c(x$colors_top)) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("color", 1, "white")
  E(g)$color <- as.factor(x$database_color)
  plot(g, vertex.label=NA)
```

When I ask `get.edge.attribute`, the correct color shows up:

```
> get.edge.attribute(g)
$color
[1] deepskyblue deepskyblue deepskyblue
Levels: deepskyblue
```

But then the plot shows that the edge is yellow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing as.factor() did the trick!

```
  x <- BrM_afterdiagnosis_centrality_urb[BrM_afterdiagnosis_centrality_urb$visitlink == i,]
  g <- graph.data.frame(x[,c(1,2)], directed = FALSE) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("urban", index = x$ahaid, value = x$urban) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("color", index = x$ahaid, value = c(x$colors_top)) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("color", 1, "white")
  E(g)$color <- =x$database_color
  plot(g, vertex.label=NA)
```